# Trying to write a buffer to a file, but keep getting segmentation faults and I can't figure out why

Tags: c, file, pthreads, fwrite

I have some code whose goal is to open/create a file, read in messages, and then write those messages to the opened/created file. Everything up to the writing to the file seems to work just fine. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "message-lib.h"

int usage( char name[] );
void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg );
sem_t mutex;
int log_fd; 

void * recv_log_msgs( void * arg ){ 
    sleep(1);
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    char buffer[1024];
    int number_bytes_read;
    FILE *fp = log_fd;
    do{
        number_bytes_read = read_msg(arg, buffer, 1024);
        printf("in recv\n");
        printf(buffer);
        fwrite(&buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), fp);
    }while(number_bytes_read > 0);
    if(number_bytes_read == 0){
        close_connection(arg);
    }
    sem_post(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}

int usage( char name[] ){
    printf( "Usage:\n" );
    printf( "\t%s <log-file-name> <UDS path>\n", name );
    return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int connection;
    pthread_t tid;
    if ( argc != 3 )
        return usage( argv[0] );

    log_fd = creat(argv[1], S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if(log_fd == -1){
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    int listener = permit_connections(argv[2]);
    if(listener == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    do{
        connection = accept_next_connection(listener);
        if(connection == -1){
            return -1;
        }
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, recv_log_msgs, connection);
    }while(connection != -1);

    close_connection(connection);    

    close_listener(listener);


    fclose(log_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

permit_connections, accept_next_connection, and read_msg are all from a library that was provided to me. I'm guessing my problem is in recv_log_msgs, but I'm not sure what it would be.

Comment: @ryyker `int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode)` is the signature for the original system call for creating files in UNIX. There may be other things obviously wrong with the above code, but `creat`is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the root of your problem:

`FILE *fp = log_fd;`

`log_fd` is a file descriptor, `fp` is a `FILE` pointer.
The two are not interchangeable, and what you need to do is use the `write(...)` system call for writing to the log file, or create the log file in some other fashion to get a hold of a `FILE`pointer to it.

`FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "w")`, might do the trick.

EDIT: As @DarrenSmith pointed out to me in the comments, you can also use
`fp = fdopen(log_fd, "w")`
and keep the rest of the code as is.

Comment: or use `fdopen` to go from the int file descriptor to the `FILE` object

Comment: @DarrenSmith Right you are - I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: That got it write, thank you so much! Only funky thing is that now the file that is being written to has the data in it, but also a huge amount of random zeros and other characters. Have you seen anything like that before?

Comment: @Withdrawnbean I guess the reason you're seeing garbage in the file, is because you're writing garbage. If you write the same number of bytes you just read, you might get the result you're after. Try `fwrite(buffer, 1, number_bytes_read, fp);`